# Using Slather w/ Fastlane

Tags: rubygems, fastlane, slather

I am trying to use Slather w/ Fastlane.

My project Gem file

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "fastlane"
gem "slather"
```

My Fastfile

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Run unit tests"
  lane :tests do
    scan(workspace: "Home.xcworkspace", device: "iPhone 6s", scheme: "Home", code_coverage: true)
  
  slather(
      output_directory: "fastlane/html",
      workspace: "Home.xcworkspace",
      html: true,
      scheme: "Home",
      proj: "Home.xcodeproj",
      ignore: [ "R.generated.swift", "Pods/*"],
      verbose: true,
      show: true
  )
  end
end
```

When running however it fails after running my tests with the following message

> Missing gem 'slather', please add the following to your local Gemfile:
>
> Add 'gem "slather"' to your Gemfile and restart fastlane

If I run `gem install slather` I get

```
Successfully installed slather-2.4.7
Parsing documentation for slather-2.4.7
Done installing documentation for slather after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: `fastlane tests`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `bundle exec fastlane ...`, in your case `bundle exec fastlane tests`, for the `Gemfile` to take effect. (Make sure you have run `bundle update` for the Gemfile's dependencies to actually be installed)